# QSortFilterProxyModel filter by date range

Tags: python, pyqt

I display 2 Tableviews from the same sql model. I want the user to be able to filter the table with a date range i.e. from 2017/03/13 to 2017/03/24 for ex. I already have a method which does this but directly on the the model like so:

```
def query_date_time(self):
    liste =[]
    self.model.setTable("Contact1")
    combodate_1 = self.dateEdit.text()
    combodate_2 = self.dateEdit_2.text()
    filter = "cast(datetime1 as datetime)between cast('{}' as datetime) and cast('{}' as datetime)".format(combodate_1,combodate_2)
    self.model.setFilter(filter)
    self.model.select()
```

The problem: it obviously filters both views but I want only the second table to be filtered not the first one.
Apparently the way to do this is to use a QSortFilterProxyModel filter. An example is provided in the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html) but this is C++ and very unclear to me.
I could I implement such a function as simply as possible or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: Why not just use two models?

Comment: Hi ekhumoro,the first view is basically a monitoring view where the user would constantly have the entirety of the data and the second view is the filtering one. I suppose i could use two models, but that would mean writing my sql queries twice and that would not be very "pythonic" :-)

Comment: If it helps, all C++ examples have been ported to Python and are included in the source package of PyQt, which you can download [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5). Also somebody put them on GitHub. Here's a direct link to the [customsortfiltermodel.py](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/itemviews/customsortfiltermodel.py) example.